# Problem with Special characters in XML conversion

Tags: java, xml

I don't know why my code does not want to change special characters from XML file, such as "<" , ">" to "&lt", "&gt" ??

I saw that you need to use escapeXML method, which I did. Also, I have put complete xml code to string with FileUtils.readFileToString() method - this works fine.

Can someone helps me out - what did I do wrong?

```
try {
            File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\project\\src\\main\\test1.xml");
            s = FileUtils.readFileToString(file, "utf-8");
            StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml10(s);



        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: What is it exactly that you are trying to accomplish with your code?

Comment: I have to put into string xml code, but not in direct XML format, such as : <code>, but it has to be &lt;code&gt;

Comment: Were you expecting the value of `s` to change? Strings are immutable... I'd expect `escapeXml10` to return a string, which you're then ignoring. Try `s = StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml10(s);` (It doesn't help that we don't know where `StringEscapeUtils` and `FileUtils` come from though.)

Comment: @JonSkeet - works like a charm!! Saved me tons of time !! ;)